# Base64 encoder form

Tags: php, html, base64, encode

I am wondering how to create a Base64 encoder with a form?

Like those websites which you input your text in a text box, press encode button, and the encoded text appears in another text box.

Thanks.

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: encode the text in base64 [see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-a-string-to-base64-in-javascript)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gabrieleromanato/qaght/ read it out

Answer (score 1):

**page.html**

```
<form action="action.php" method="post">
 <p>String to base64 encode: <input type="text" name="string" /></p>
 <p><input type="submit" /></p>
</form>
```

**action.php**

```
$string = isset($_POST['string']) ? $_POST['string'] : "";
echo base64_encode($string);
```